# How to get 'add to cart button' to appear where I place it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code at the moment which adds a button after the 'Add to cart' button on my woocommerce site. This is a piece of code I found online.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_simple_add_to_cart_10', 20 );
function additional_simple_add_to_cart_10() {
    global $product;

// Only for variable product type 
    $href = '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr( $product->get_id() ) . '&quantity=10';
    $class = 'ingle_add_to_cart_button-10 button alt';
    $style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
    $button_text = __( "10 Tickets", "woocommerce" );

    // Output
    echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" href="'.$href.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';

}
```

I would like to edit this so that the button moves to wherever I place this code on my page, just want a generic button that adds 10 units to cart- as it currently automatically puts it after add to cart.

Comment: you want this to be a short code?

Comment: @HassaanAli I have a box that I want this to be placed in so if that would allow me to put this in there then great!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the short code function from WordPress to create a short code for your function additional_simple_add_to_cart_10. Here's the example:

```
add_shortcode('add-to-cart', 'additional_simple_add_to_cart_10');
```

Comment: Ok, this part worked, but I still have the original button in the add to cart area. So two buttons on my page. What should I change with the original code?

Comment: you can either hide it with a css or you can comment out this code. 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_simple_add_to_cart_10', 20 );

Comment: if it works mark it as an answer so that others could see as well.